# Can I use Kafka queue in my Rest WEBSERVICE

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a rest based application deployed in server(tomcat) ,
Every request comes to server it takes 1 second of time to serve, now I have a issue, sometimes Server receive more request then it is capable of serving which making server non responsive. Now I was thinking if I can store the requests in a queue so that server can pull request and serve that request and handle the pick time issue.

Now I was thinking can Kafka be helpful for this, if yes any pointer where I can start.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Kafka (or any other messaging system for this ex- ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ etc).

When WebService receives request, add request (with all details required to process it) in Kafka queue (using Kafka message producer [details](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html))

Separate service (having Kafka consumer [details](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)) will read from topic(queue) and process it.

In case need to send message to client when request is processed, server can push information to client using WebSocket (Or client can poll for request status however this need request status endpoint and will cause load on that endpoint).

Comment: Thanks Kaushal for you inputs, But how can send the response to the same call, as same source is firing multiple calls.

Comment: One of option is, you can set request id (X-Request-ID or X-Correlation-ID) in client when sending any request to server (or server can create id and send in response, to be used for tracing request status) . When this request is dequeued from kafka topic (ensure saving request id as part of kafka message) and processed, send message from server using websocket. Include request id as part of message pushed from server. This way client can correlate which web socket frame was sent for which http request.

Comment: Alternative option (however not optimal solution) client can poll in separate http call (careful it will cause unnecessary http request when request still being processed or in queue). This option works if you don't want to implement websocket for push notification from server.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Kafka would be helpful in your case. If you use a Kafka broker, it will allow you to face with a peak of requests. The requests will be stored in a queue as you mentionned and be treated by your server at its own speed.

As your are using tomcat, I guess you developped your server in Java. Apache Kafka propose a Java API which is quite easy to use.

Comment: I think you can use Rabbitmq, too.